# Slow shutdown when external NTFS hard drive is connected

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown, usb-drive, ntfs, external-hdd

I'm fairly new to Linux (1 year experience).

I had Xubuntu 18.04 LTS and now running Xubuntu 20.04 LTS and I'm stilling running into the same issue.

My system is E7500 dual core / 4 GB DDR3 with ext4 for Xubuntu and a small NTFS partition for Windows 7 (not auto-mounted at startup).

Whenever an NTFS formatted external USB 2.0 hard drive is connected, whether mounted or not, system shutdown takes about *2~3 mins* (correction: 30 seconds measured by journalctl). I've the exact issue with three different external HDDs.

Usually, system shutdown takes around 30 seconds when no external HDD is connected.

I've turned off shutdown splash screen and the system seems to pause at request system halt line most of the time.

It's fairly critical to me because we have random blackouts several times a day. My 600W UPS does not have enough time to recharge if the battery is fully depleted each time.

**Update:**

After using journalclt to measure shutdown times:

- On Battery: 4 seconds (without USB Drive), 23 seconds (with external NTFS USB Drive)
- On Mains power: 4 seconds (without USB Drive), 14 seconds (with external NTFS USB Drive)

It seems that having an external USB NTFS HDD prolongs shutdown process by 20 seconds while powered on UPS battery.

Comment: Are you saying that shutdown is fast if the drive is not connected?

Comment: yes it's much faster without ntfs external usb hard drive.

Comment: Look at the logs. Read `man journalctl`. `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's logs.

Comment: Thank you, journalctl command is really helpful.

Power  without any external USB Drive  with external NTFS HDD (accessed and files written)
Battery  4 seconds    23 seconds
Mains  4 seconds    14 seconds

It seems that having an external NTFS HDD prolongs the shutdown by 20 seconds while powered on UPS battery. I don't know if it's a power related issue.
in journalctl, it seems that fail2ban.service and user@1000.service got stuck at times (not at every shutdown or reboot).